# C# Process and Thread Termination When Time is Up - Waitable Timer

Tags: c#, multithreading, process, timer

I am trying to create the following effect:

I have x number of threads running at the same time and I want them all to stop when a timer goes off.

The only thing I can think of doing is having a shared boolean value that changes when the time is up. Does anyone know how to do this with a threading timer and the AutoResetEvent?

I am having a hard time finding out how to use the Autoreset event...

Do you know of a better way to achieve this effect?

What about with processes?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than share a boolean, use a [ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx) and have each thread wait on it.

```
private static void ThreadDelegate(object state)
{
    object[] stateArray = (object[])state;
    ManualResetEvent resetEvent = (ManualResetEvent)stateArray[0];

    //Do some work.
    ...

    resetEvent.WaitOne();
}
```

This will block the thread until you call `resetEvent.Set();` I suppose the best answer to this really depends on how you structure your code. What I have suggested depends upon the `//Do some work` bit doing something like creating a `Timer` and invoking a callback at some interval.